# How to use client secrets with Gatling

Tags: gatling

Our team has recently been tasked with porting our existing suite of load tests to gatling and run them through gatling frontline. The snag is that you need a short lived access token to communicate with our service under test and after scouring through the documentation I cannot for the life of me find any way to store secrets in gatling frontline and use them in the tests. This is however extremely basic functionallity, and I think everyone in the organization assumed that this was in place before licenses were bought etc.

Does anyone know how to store and access secrets in gatling frontline?

Comment: You should reach out to our support (channel depends on how you've subscribed).

Comment: @StéphaneLANDELLE I could not find any reference to a support email on our frontline instance or on the gatling.io which is why I asked here instead. How are you supposed to get support for gatling frontline?

Comment: Please reach out https://gatling.io/contact/

Comment: @StéphaneLANDELLE I tried filling out the form, but you only get a 404 after submitting so I assume it does not work and that you do not receive any messages through that channel

Comment: We've received your message and someone is going to route you to the proper channel. We're investigating the 404 issue.